# Get the specific user data in modal on click from API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I'm only getting the user ID or fName etc, but not getting all the detail at once in the modal ( Pop-up ). I wanted to get only one specific user data in the modal.

HTML code

```
<table class="table table-striped ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#ID</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Gender</th>
          <th scope="col">User Detail</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    
        <tr *ngFor="let user of newdata.users;">
          <td>{{user?.id}}</td>
          <td>{{user?.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{user?.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{user?.gender}}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" (click)="openModal()">See Details</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

In the .ts file I'm able to get the all the data from API. But I wanted to try to get one user data onclick the button which is (open)="openModal()"

.ts Code

```
  newdata:any = { users: [] };

  constructor (private userAPIData:StudentDataService){}

  selectedUser:any;

  UserClicked(newdata:any){
    let selectedUser = JSON.stringify(newdata);
    // this.selectedUser=newdata;
    alert(selectedUser);
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userAPIData.getdata().subscribe(res =>{
      // this.newdata= Object.values(res);
      this.newdata = res;
      console.log(this.newdata.users)
  })
  }

  display = "none";
  openModal() {
      this.display = "block";   
  }
  onCloseHandled() {
    this.display = "none";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the user object inside the method like so

html

```
(open)="openModal(user)"
```

ts

```
openModal(user: any) {
      let selectedUser = JSON.stringify(user); // this variable contains the user details
      this.selectedUser=selectedUser;
      alert(selectedUser);
      this.display = "block";   
}
```

Updated Code:

You need to pass the `user` object that you are using in the html into the method and just store it in a variable, please not that inside the model you are showing a popup with a table, so that user should be stored inside an array only, please refer the below stackblitz!

ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-data',
  templateUrl: './student-data.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
})
export class StudentDataComponent {
  newdata: any = { users: [] };

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  selectedUser: any;

  UserClicked(user: any) {
    let selectedUser = [{ ...user }];
    this.display = 'block';

    this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    // alert(selectedUser);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get('https://dummyjson.com/users').subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.newdata = res;
      console.log(this.newdata.users);
    });
  }

  display = 'none';

  // let selectedUser2 : any;

  onCloseHandled() {
    this.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#ID</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Gender</th>
      <th scope="col">User Detail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of newdata.users">
      <td>{{ user?.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ user?.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user?.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user?.gender }}</td>
      <td>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
          (click)="UserClicked(user)"
        >
          See Details
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" [ngStyle]="{ display: display }">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">User Details</h4>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          aria-label="Close"
          (click)="onCloseHandled()"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Model body text</p>

        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#ID</th>
              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Gender</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let user of selectedUser">
              <td>{{ user?.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ user?.firstName }}</td>
              <td>{{ user?.lastName }}</td>
              <td>{{ user?.gender }}</td>
              <td>{{ user?.email }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-default"
          (click)="onCloseHandled()"
        >
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4cmgpc)

Comment: This is showing the empty table of modal.

Comment: @MuhammadAnas Please share the model code also, if possible a stackblitz!

Comment: @MuhammadAnas updated my answer!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jvivtk?file=src%2FstudentDataComponent%2Fstudent-data.component.html

Comment: In the above code alert is giving the undefined value.

Comment: @MuhammadAnas updated my answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256124/discussion-between-muhammad-anas-and-naren-murali).